# What could be done to prevent this MailKit SMTP failure?

Tags: c#, wpf, smtp, mailkit

I use the recommended MailKit.Net.Smtp class in my WPF C# application where the user(client) sends a log file from and to a dedicated Gmail by clicking a button. But when I tried on a friend's computer I get an exception. (I encounter [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/405567/ssmtp-unable-to-send-message-using-external-mail-server-smtp)  and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/635139/how-to-fix-send-mail-authorization-failed-534-5-7-14) question but in my case, I don't know how to use it for C#)

The code I use:

```
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                
                client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);

                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                
                 client.Authenticate(login, password);
                 client.Send(message);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                client.Dispose();
            }
           
        }
```

And here is the exception logged:

```
Warning: 534: 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt
5.7.14 M0QLqwGEsymkDwo_w1PdtomM64NjeHlfRTxHSCRLrHD4dWryXDkqTLOTTdXp3j_w0jh5x
5.7.14 23oVaJfk24KAG9mFqOrGF1US1WDZx2PRou0xeN9x9s3iRl9Ash2T54rY_wMpsVtw>
5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
5.7.14  Learn more at
5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t17sm1641881ljt.1 - gsmtp: MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: 534: 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt
5.7.14 M0QLqwGEsymkDwo_w1PdtomM64NjeHlfRTxHSCRLrHD4dWryXDkqTLOTTdXp3j_w0jh5x
5.7.14 23oVaJfk24KAG9mFqOrGF1US1WDZx2PRou0xeN9x9s3iRl9Ash2T54rY_wMpsVtw>
5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
5.7.14  Learn more at
5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t17sm1641881ljt.1 - gsmtp ---> MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpCommandException: 5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt
5.7.14 M0QLqwGEsymkDwo_w1PdtomM64NjeHlfRTxHSCRLrHD4dWryXDkqTLOTTdXp3j_w0jh5x
5.7.14 23oVaJfk24KAG9mFqOrGF1US1WDZx2PRou0xeN9x9s3iRl9Ash2T54rY_wMpsVtw>
5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
5.7.14  Learn more at
5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t17sm1641881ljt.1 - gsmtp
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.<AuthenticateAsync>d__87.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Authenticate(Encoding encoding, ICredentials credentials, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.MailService.Authenticate(Encoding encoding, String userName, String password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Cont.MainWindow.SendEmailFromClient() 6/28/2021 9:40:27 PM
```

Now my WPF app might be run in another part of the world and I need to receive the log file and fix this sending error. I already made "Allow less secure apps" ON and was able to receive emails from my computer. But somehow it is not adequate.

Answer (score 1):

The error message from the server in the logs tells you precisely what you need to do. You need to login to Google Mail from the machine you are connecting to SMTP from (in this case, your friend's machine).

This is a safety precaution from Google and it will not let you authenticate with the SMTP server until you first login via a web browser.

You might be able to get around this by using an app-specific password. Somewhere in your Google Mail settings, you can generate app-specific passwords for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if I send my application to a client I dont want them to login the email by browser. The login and password is embedded in the code. Actually I clicked https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha from my computer and called my friend to run the program again and it worked. So he didnt do anything by browser but I clicked on https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha from my computer. But I would like to eliminate this issue for other clients.

Comment: This is why I suggested app-specific passwords - I believe they get around the need to login via a web browser.

Comment: Thank you I will try!